# Spring boot for back office and Android app for all users

Tags: android, spring, mongodb, sqlite, android-studio

So I'm currently working on an app for movies listing and scoring.
I came to the idea of creating all back-office functionalities (user management, movie management,etc) with the spring framework and angular for the visualization.
All works just fine with web services !

Now for the front office and public usage, I would like it in Android. Everyone wanting to use the app should be authenticated, then can view all movies and choose their favorite ones.

My question is how do I get all movies from the mongoDB database and through the spring framework onto the Android app? (storing it into sqlite I guess?)
How can the current user view his own list of favorite movies and rate them?

PS: Movies have their logos too, so how do I transfer images via web services??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define api for mobile app from with it can load concrete data. You will propably have separate endpoints for images, CRUD for user list, voting on certain items, authentication and so on. You question is to broad to be covered in one answer, we would basically need to design you whole mobile and backend app.

Comment: Thanks for your response Igor!

I actually only need an idea of how to design and conceptualize this with the working back end that I already have up and running.

Okay so do you think I should load the data that I'll need for the mobile app onto the SQLite?
And what kind of seperate endpoints for the images?

Comment: It depends. If you do not need your app to work offline, you can always get data from the backend, if you need, then use SQLite. Images, even small ones, will take considerably more memory than text/json/xml responses, so it is good idea to load them separately. For example, you will have endpoint domain/images/{id} which will give you image of certain resources. You propably will also want to implement some caching mechanism for that:)

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot Igor! This was really helpful